# How to switch over to particular page in pdf by it's page no in iphone

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.2, ios5, uipageviewcontroller

Hi i am using UIPageViewController in ios 5, for example i'm having 10 pages in that i want to switch to 8th page from 2nd page means how can i implement this functionalities in UIPageViewController, please anyone help me to get out of this issue..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208871/is-it-possible-to-turn-page-programmatically-in-uipageviewcontroller)