# How to use setViewController:direction:animated method

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

How can i use setViewControllers method in page view controller, is there any example available of it. Or can some body post it any sample code that how can we use it to navigate to other view controllers.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, i want to make page curl animation through page view controller by button action, and i found that it can be done by this method. But what to call in this method i have not found any sample of this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered googling it out before posting here? doesn't look like...

Here are a few links..

[UIPageViewController - how Can I jump to a particular page number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334967/uipageviewcontroller-how-can-i-jump-to-a-particular-page-number)

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application

Comment: I have checked these links already, so i suggests you to look again at my question. This method is not used in any of these.