# Embeded Container and UIPageViewController

Tags: ios

I had Embeded a page view controller in a container and added 3 buttons on top of it
want to manipulate that page view controller in the container how do it do it
can anyone please guide me
on this one

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

- Identify the index of the `viewcontroller` based on the button clicked
- Get the view controller at the selected index
- Pass it to the `UIPageViewController`, [UIPageViewController - how Can I jump to a particular page number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334967/uipageviewcontroller-how-can-i-jump-to-a-particular-page-number)