# Turn page programmatically in UIPageViewController when using UIPageViewControllerDataSource?

Tags: ios, ios5, uikit

I have an `UIPageViewController` and a class which conforms to `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` and manages the UIViewControllers which UIPageViewController displays. It all runs well when turning the pages is initiated by the user. But now I want to do that programmatically.

I've found that there is a very similar question here on SO which answers the question for a static amount of ViewControllers: [Is it possible to Turn page programmatically in UIPageViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208871/is-it-possible-to-turn-page-programmatically-in-uipageviewcontroller)

But I'm unable to adapt the answers to the use of UIPageViewControllerDataSource. I was thinking that there must be something like:

```
- (void)setCurrentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

I suppose I'm just overlooking something here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Method mentioned in the answer ( `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` ) sets the *current* view controller and is exactly what you need.
With the first param you define the view controller(s), you want to display. Use one if you don't have a spine, if you book is left/right use two.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the last line of your answer which says "Use one if you don't have a spine, if you book is left/right use two."

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick haha! He's referring to the ability for iPads to have two pages showing on the screen at once. If the pages on the screen are a "book" with a "spine," then you should set two view controllers as active at once. Otherwise, just show one.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but the following implementation calls delegate and dataSource methods for turning to previous or next page (But doesn't check if delegate or dataSource is set):

```
- (IBAction)navigateReverse:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *controller = [self.dataSource pageViewController:self viewControllerBeforeViewController:self.designViewControllers[self.currentIndex]];

    if (!controller)
    {
        return;
    }

    NSArray *newViewControllers = @[controller];

    NSArray *previousViewControllers = self.viewControllers;

    __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    [self.delegate pageViewController:self willTransitionToViewControllers:newViewControllers];
    [self setViewControllers:newViewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [weakSelf.delegate pageViewController:weakSelf didFinishAnimating:finished previousViewControllers:previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:finished];
    }];
}

- (IBAction)navigateForward:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *controller = [self.dataSource pageViewController:self viewControllerAfterViewController:self.designViewControllers[self.currentIndex]];

    if (!controller)
    {
        return;
    }

    NSArray *newViewControllers = @[controller];

    NSArray *previousViewControllers = self.viewControllers;

    __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    [self.delegate pageViewController:self willTransitionToViewControllers:newViewControllers];
    [self setViewControllers:newViewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [weakSelf.delegate pageViewController:weakSelf didFinishAnimating:finished previousViewControllers:previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:finished];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a easy project with that functionality:

https://github.com/delarcomarta/AMPageViewController

Hope this can help you.