# move pageViewController with button

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

Basically I'd like to move my PageViewController not only with swipe but also with buttons.

```
@IBAction func nextButtonAction(_ sender: Any){

}
```

[My PageViewController looks like in this guide](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/)

**What I have:**

- PageViewController
- 3 Viewcontrollers

Sorry if it's a duplicate didn't found exactly same situation

> tried to call UIPageViewControllerDataSource on each ViewController
>   but didn't work also I think this is not the best approach

**Edited:** 
This is my PageViewController

```
class PageVC: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    lazy var VCarr: [UIViewController] = {

        return [self.VCInstance(name: "signUpVerification"),
        self.VCInstance(name: "signUpVerification1"),
        self.VCInstance(name: "signUpVerification2"),
        ]
    }()

    func VCInstance(name:String) -> UIViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:name)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self
        if let firsVC = VCarr.first {

            setViewControllers([firsVC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = VCarr.index(of: viewController) else { return nil }
        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
            return nil
        }
        return VCarr[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = VCarr.index(of: viewController) else { return nil }
        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
        guard nextIndex < VCarr.count else {
            return nil
        }
        return VCarr[nextIndex]
    }



}

extension PageVC {
    func goToNextPage(animated: Bool = true, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
        if let currentViewController = VCarr.first {
            if let nextPage = dataSource?.pageViewController(self, viewControllerAfter: currentViewController) //for some reasons there's nil {
                setViewControllers([nextPage], direction: .forward, animated: animated, completion: completion)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is Viewcontroller where I call it:

```
var pageVC = PageVC()
@IBAction func nextButtonAction(_ sender: Any){

   pageVC.goToNextPage()

}
```

**Solution:**

```
YourViewController: {
 @IBAction func nextButtonAction(_ sender: Any){
        let pageViewController = self.parent as! PageVC
        pageViewController.nextPageWithIndex(index: 1)


    }
}

PageViewController: {
   func nextPageWithIndex(index: Int) {
        setViewControllers([VCarr[index]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Checkout this question :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633059/uipageviewcontroller-how-do-i-correctly-jump-to-a-specific-page-without-messing/18602186

Comment: I find this Answer is the best, hope it help [see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44691025/2510116)

Answer (score 8):

To move page viewController to by button click you can achieve very simply by using following extension

```
extension UIPageViewController {
    func goToNextPage(animated: Bool = true, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
        if let currentViewController = viewControllers?[0] {
            if let nextPage = dataSource?.pageViewController(self, viewControllerAfter: currentViewController) {
                setViewControllers([nextPage], direction: .forward, animated: animated, completion: completion)
            }
        }
    }

    func goToPreviousPage(animated: Bool = true, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
        if let currentViewController = viewControllers?[0] {
            if let previousPage = dataSource?.pageViewController(self, viewControllerBefore: currentViewController){
                setViewControllers([previousPage], direction: .reverse, animated: true, completion: completion)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**To move forward**

```
self.pageViewController.goToNextPage()
```

**To move backward**

```
self.pageViewController.goToPreviousPage()
```

don't forget to check whether the index available or not

**for example:**

```
if pageArray.count > currentIdex {
self.pageViewController.goToNextPage()
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: thank you for help but unfortunately I get an error.

`index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray`

Comment: did you get the crash while swipe next page or crash only happen when click on button?

Comment: if you mean swipe with gesture then no it works and it should be. Problem with the button `I get this error Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions`

Comment: only with button

Comment: Have you remove` extension PageVC {
    func goToNextPage(animated: Bool = true, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
        if let currentViewController = VCarr.first {
            if let nextPage = dataSource?.pageViewController(self, viewControllerAfter: currentViewController) //for some reasons there's nil {
                setViewControllers([nextPage], direction: .forward, animated: animated, completion: completion)
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: yes I did just to see what it does. now my extension looks like this

`extension PageVC {
   func goToNextPage(animated: Bool = true, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
     self.dataSource = self
    if let currentViewController = VCarr.first {
        if let nextPage = dataSource?.pageViewController(self, viewControllerAfter: currentViewController) {
            setViewControllers([nextPage], direction: .forward, animated: animated, completion: completion)
            }
        }
    }
}`
and i get this error 
`Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for`

Comment: use the extension which i post in answer that will solve this issue

Comment: I found this helpful. Thanks!. Save current index globally and need to use like viewControllers?[currentIndex]. Update currentIndex on UIPageViewController delegates accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this method in your button Action for moving from first View Controller to second:

```
self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([self.viewControllerAtIndex(1)!], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
pageControl2.currentPage = 1
```

Rest you can add your current PageTracker using `PageControl`.

```
self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([self.viewControllerAtIndex(pageControl.currentPage + 1)!], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
pageControl.currentPage += 1
```