# UIPageViewController programmatically turning pages does not update Page Indicator

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uipageviewcontroller, ios6.1

When I programmatically turn the page in a UIPageViewController using a method similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8678367/1103584), the Page Indicators are not updated.  Swiping to the next/previous page updates the page indicators as expected.  What do I need to do to update the Page Indicators when programmatically turning the page?  i.e. How do I set the current "index" after programmatically changing the page so the Page Indicators know which page indicator to show as active?

I noticed in the documentation, the following is stated:

> If both of the methods in “Supporting a Page Indicator” are implemented and the page view controller’s transition style is UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll, a page indicator is visible. Both of these methods are called after the setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion: method is called. **After gesture-driven navigation, these methods are not called.** The index is updated automatically and the number of view controllers is expected to remain constant.

(see bold text above)

[UIPageViewController documenatation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerDataSourceProtocolRef/UIPageViewControllerDataSource.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPageViewControllerDataSource)

Does this imply that if you don't use a gesture to turn the page, then there is no way to update the UIPageIndicators?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement the following data source protocol method with the correct page index:

```
- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
 NSInteger currentPageIndex=0;
 //find out actual page index of the current view controller
return currentPageIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are setting the **number of pages** and the **first page** one time, and cannot add (or remove) pages to the `Page Control` without calling `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` again.
It is basically a write-only property defined in the `DataSource` protocol.