# Disable swipe gesture in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I have 3 ViewControllers in one ViewController

ViewPagerController = self -> it is a viewController and has UIPageViewController init

ProgramQuestionViewController = it based from ViewPagerController

QuestionViewController = my content view it is shown in the middle of ProgramViewController

this is my ViewPagerController

```
@interface ViewPagerController () <UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
NSMutableArray *dataAnswers;
}

@property UIScrollView *tabsView;
@property UIView *contentView;

@property UIPageViewController *pageViewController;
@property (assign) id<UIScrollViewDelegate> actualDelegate;
@property (assign)bool isValidPage;

@property (assign)bool isSonraki;
// Tab and content cache
@property NSMutableArray *tabs;
@property NSMutableArray *contents;

// Options
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *tabHeight;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *tabOffset;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *tabWidth;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *tabLocation;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *startFromSecondTab;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *centerCurrentTab;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *fixFormerTabsPositions;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *fixLatterTabsPositions;
@property (nonatomic,retain)UIButton *backButton;
@property (nonatomic,retain)UIButton *nextButton;

@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger tabCount;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger activeTabIndex;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger activeContentIndex;

@property (getter = isAnimatingToTab, assign) BOOL animatingToTab;
@property (getter = isDefaultSetupDone, assign) BOOL defaultSetupDone;


@property (nonatomic) UIColor *indicatorColor;
@property (nonatomic) UIColor *tabsViewBackgroundColor;
@property (nonatomic) UIColor *contentViewBackgroundColor;

@end

@implementation ViewPagerController

@synthesize tabHeight = _tabHeight;
@synthesize tabOffset = _tabOffset;
@synthesize tabWidth = _tabWidth;
@synthesize tabLocation = _tabLocation;
@synthesize startFromSecondTab = _startFromSecondTab;
@synthesize centerCurrentTab = _centerCurrentTab;
@synthesize fixFormerTabsPositions = _fixFormerTabsPositions;
@synthesize fixLatterTabsPositions = _fixLatterTabsPositions;
@synthesize isValidPage;
@synthesize backButton;
@synthesize nextButton;
@synthesize isSonraki;


- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if (self) {
    [self defaultSettings];
}
return self;
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    [self defaultSettings];
}
return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
isSonraki=false;
isValidPage=true;
dataAnswers =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIImageView *pagerBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_bg.png"]];

pagerBackground.frame=CGRectMake(0, 800, self.view.frame.size.width, 160);
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:234.0/255.0 green:234.0/255.0 blue:234.0/255.0 alpha:0.75]];

backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 875, 87, 45)];
[backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"prev_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizerBack = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleBackTapGesture:)];
//[backButton addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizerBack];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleBackTapGesture:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
backButton.hidden=YES;

nextButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[nextButton setFrame:CGRectMake(620, 875, 87, 45)];
[nextButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"next_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizerNext = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleNextTapGesture:)];
//[nextButton addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizerNext];
[nextButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleNextTapGesture:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gr in [self.pageViewController gestureRecognizers]) {
    [gr setEnabled:NO];
}
[self.view addSubview:nextButton];
[self.view addSubview:backButton];

}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
//Touch gestures below top bar should not make the page turn.
//EDITED Check for only Tap here instead.
if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if (touchPoint.y > 40) {
        return NO;
    }
    else if (touchPoint.x > 50 && touchPoint.x < 430) {//Let the buttons in the middle of the top bar receive the touch
        return NO;
    }
}
return YES;
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

// Do setup if it's not done yet
if (![self isDefaultSetupDone]) {
    [self defaultSetup];
    NSLog(@"hello");
}
}
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

// Re-layout sub views
[self layoutSubviews];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {

CGFloat topLayoutGuide = 0.0;

CGRect frame = self.tabsView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 150.0;
frame.origin.y = [self.tabLocation boolValue] ? topLayoutGuide : CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) - [self.tabHeight floatValue];
frame.size.width = 450;//CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame);
frame.size.height = [self.tabHeight floatValue];
self.tabsView.frame = frame;



frame = self.contentView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0.0;
frame.origin.y = [self.tabLocation boolValue] ? topLayoutGuide + CGRectGetHeight(self.tabsView.frame) : topLayoutGuide;
frame.size.width = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame);
frame.size.height = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) - (topLayoutGuide + CGRectGetHeight(self.tabsView.frame)) - CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame);
self.contentView.frame = frame;
}


- (IBAction)handleTapGesture:(id)sender {


}

- (IBAction)handleNextTapGesture:(id)sender {

//UIView *myvview=[self.dataSource viewPager:self contentViewForTabAtIndex:0];
//backButton.hidden=NO;

UIViewController *viewController = [self.dataSource viewPager:self contentViewControllerForTabAtIndex:_activeContentIndex];
UIViewController *xvc=[LoggedinUser sharedCenter].myQuestionView;


[self saveMyData:xvc];

if (isValidPage) {
    [self selectTabAtIndex:self.activeContentIndex+1];
}


}

- (IBAction)handleBackTapGesture:(id)sender {

if(self.activeTabIndex==0)
{
    backButton.hidden=YES;
}
else
{
    backButton.hidden=NO;
}

UIViewController *viewController = [self.dataSource viewPager:self contentViewControllerForTabAtIndex:_activeContentIndex];
UIViewController *xvc=[LoggedinUser sharedCenter].myQuestionView;


[self saveMyData:xvc];

if (isValidPage) {
    [self selectTabAtIndex:self.activeContentIndex-1];
}

}

- (void)setActiveTabIndex:(NSUInteger)activeTabIndex {

TabView *activeTabView;

// Set to-be-inactive tab unselected
activeTabView = [self tabViewAtIndex:self.activeTabIndex];
activeTabView.selected = NO;

// Set to-be-active tab selected
activeTabView = [self tabViewAtIndex:activeTabIndex];
activeTabView.selected = YES;

// Set current activeTabIndex
_activeTabIndex = activeTabIndex;

// Bring tab to active position
// Position the tab in center if centerCurrentTab option is provided as YES
UIView *tabView = [self tabViewAtIndex:self.activeTabIndex];
CGRect frame = tabView.frame;

if ([self.centerCurrentTab boolValue]) {

    frame.origin.x += (CGRectGetWidth(frame) / 2);
    frame.origin.x -= CGRectGetWidth(self.tabsView.frame) / 2;
    frame.size.width = CGRectGetWidth(self.tabsView.frame);

    if (frame.origin.x < 0) {
        frame.origin.x = 0;
    }

    if ((frame.origin.x + CGRectGetWidth(frame)) > self.tabsView.contentSize.width) {
        frame.origin.x = (self.tabsView.contentSize.width - CGRectGetWidth(self.tabsView.frame));
    }
} else {

    //frame.origin.x -= [self.tabOffset floatValue];
    frame.origin.x -= [self.tabOffset floatValue];
    frame.size.width = CGRectGetWidth(self.tabsView.frame);
}

[self.tabsView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}
- (void)setActiveContentIndex:(NSUInteger)activeContentIndex {

// Get the desired viewController
UIViewController *viewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:activeContentIndex];

if (!viewController) {
    viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

// __weak pageViewController to be used in blocks to prevent retaining strong reference to self
__weak UIPageViewController *weakPageViewController = self.pageViewController;
__weak ViewPagerController *weakSelf = self;

if (activeContentIndex == self.activeContentIndex) {

    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[viewController]
                                      direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                       animated:NO
                                     completion:^(BOOL completed) {
                                         weakSelf.animatingToTab = NO;
                                     }];

} else if (!(activeContentIndex + 1 == self.activeContentIndex || activeContentIndex - 1 == self.activeContentIndex)) {

    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[viewController]
                                      direction:(activeContentIndex < self.activeContentIndex) ? UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse : UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                       animated:YES
                                     completion:^(BOOL completed) {

                                         weakSelf.animatingToTab = NO;

                                         // Set the current page again to obtain synchronisation between tabs and content
                                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                             [weakPageViewController setViewControllers:@[viewController]
                                                                              direction:(activeContentIndex < weakSelf.activeContentIndex) ? UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse : UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                                                               animated:NO
                                                                             completion:nil];
                                         });
                                     }];

} else {

    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[viewController]
                                      direction:(activeContentIndex < self.activeContentIndex) ? UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse : UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                       animated:YES
                                     completion:^(BOOL completed) {
                                         weakSelf.animatingToTab = NO;
                                     }];
}

// Clean out of sight contents
NSInteger index;
index = self.activeContentIndex - 1;
if (index >= 0 &&
    index != activeContentIndex &&
    index != activeContentIndex - 1)
{
    [self.contents replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNull null]];
}
index = self.activeContentIndex;
if (index != activeContentIndex - 1 &&
    index != activeContentIndex &&
    index != activeContentIndex + 1)
{
    [self.contents replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNull null]];
}
index = self.activeContentIndex + 1;
if (index < self.contents.count &&
    index != activeContentIndex &&
    index != activeContentIndex + 1)
{
    [self.contents replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNull null]];
}

_activeContentIndex = activeContentIndex;
}



- (void)reloadData {

// Empty all options and colors
// So that, ViewPager will reflect the changes
// Empty all options
_tabHeight = nil;
_tabOffset = nil;
_tabWidth = nil;
_tabLocation = nil;
_startFromSecondTab = nil;
_centerCurrentTab = nil;
_fixFormerTabsPositions = nil;
_fixLatterTabsPositions = nil;

// Empty all colors
_indicatorColor = nil;
_tabsViewBackgroundColor = nil;
_contentViewBackgroundColor = nil;

// Call to setup again with the updated data
[self defaultSetup];
}
- (void)selectTabAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

if (index >= self.tabCount) {
    return;
}

self.animatingToTab = YES;

// Set activeTabIndex
self.activeTabIndex = index;

// Set activeContentIndex
self.activeContentIndex = index;

// Inform delegate about the change
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(viewPager:didChangeTabToIndex:)]) {
    [self.delegate viewPager:self didChangeTabToIndex:self.activeTabIndex];
}
}

- (void)setNeedsReloadOptions {

// If our delegate doesn't respond to our options method, return
// Otherwise reload options
if (![self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(viewPager:valueForOption:withDefault:)]) {
    return;
}

// Update these options
self.tabWidth = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self.delegate viewPager:self valueForOption:ViewPagerOptionTabWidth withDefault:kTabWidth]];
self.tabOffset = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self.delegate viewPager:self valueForOption:ViewPagerOptionTabOffset withDefault:kTabOffset]];
self.centerCurrentTab = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self.delegate viewPager:self valueForOption:ViewPagerOptionCenterCurrentTab withDefault:kCenterCurrentTab]];
self.fixFormerTabsPositions = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self.delegate viewPager:self valueForOption:ViewPagerOptionFixFormerTabsPositions withDefault:kFixFormerTabsPositions]];
self.fixLatterTabsPositions = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self.delegate viewPager:self valueForOption:ViewPagerOptionFixLatterTabsPositions withDefault:kFixLatterTabsPositions]];

// We should update contentSize property of our tabsView, so we should recalculate it with the new values
CGFloat contentSizeWidth = 0;

// Give the standard offset if fixFormerTabsPositions is provided as YES
if ([self.fixFormerTabsPositions boolValue]) {

    // And if the centerCurrentTab is provided as YES fine tune the offset according to it
    if ([self.centerCurrentTab boolValue]) {
        contentSizeWidth = (CGRectGetWidth(self.tabsView.frame) - [self.tabWidth floatValue]) / 2.0;
    } else {
        contentSizeWidth = [self.tabOffset floatValue];
    }
}

// Update every tab's frame
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < self.tabCount; i++) {

    UIView *tabView = [self tabViewAtIndex:i];

    CGRect frame = tabView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = contentSizeWidth;
    frame.size.width = [self.tabWidth floatValue];
    tabView.frame = frame;

    contentSizeWidth += CGRectGetWidth(tabView.frame);
}

// Extend contentSizeWidth if fixLatterTabsPositions is provided YES
if ([self.fixLatterTabsPositions boolValue]) {

    // And if the centerCurrentTab is provided as YES fine tune the content size according to it
    if ([self.centerCurrentTab boolValue]) {
        contentSizeWidth += (CGRectGetWidth(self.tabsView.frame) - [self.tabWidth floatValue]) / 2.0;
    } else {
        contentSizeWidth += CGRectGetWidth(self.tabsView.frame) - [self.tabWidth floatValue] - [self.tabOffset floatValue];
    }
}

// Update tabsView's contentSize with the new width
self.tabsView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentSizeWidth, [self.tabHeight floatValue]);

}
- (void)setNeedsReloadColors {

// If our delegate doesn't respond to our colors method, return
// Otherwise reload colors
if (![self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(viewPager:colorForComponent:withDefault:)]) {
    return;
}

// These colors will be updated
UIColor *indicatorColor;
UIColor *tabsViewBackgroundColor;
UIColor *contentViewBackgroundColor;

// Get indicatorColor and check if it is different from the current one
// If it is, update it
indicatorColor = [self.delegate viewPager:self colorForComponent:ViewPagerIndicator withDefault:kIndicatorColor];

if (![self.indicatorColor isEqualToColor:indicatorColor]) {

    // We will iterate through all of the tabs to update its indicatorColor
    [self.tabs enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(TabView *tabView, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        tabView.indicatorColor = indicatorColor;
    }];

    // Update indicatorColor to check again later
    self.indicatorColor = indicatorColor;
}

// Get tabsViewBackgroundColor and check if it is different from the current one
// If it is, update it
tabsViewBackgroundColor = [self.delegate viewPager:self colorForComponent:ViewPagerTabsView withDefault:kTabsViewBackgroundColor];

if (![self.tabsViewBackgroundColor isEqualToColor:tabsViewBackgroundColor]) {

    // Update it
    self.tabsView.backgroundColor = tabsViewBackgroundColor;

    // Update tabsViewBackgroundColor to check again later
    self.tabsViewBackgroundColor = tabsViewBackgroundColor;
}

// Get contentViewBackgroundColor and check if it is different from the current one
// Yeah update it, too
//contentViewBackgroundColor = [self.delegate viewPager:self colorForComponent:ViewPagerContent withDefault:kContentViewBackgroundColor];

//if (![self.contentViewBackgroundColor isEqualToColor:contentViewBackgroundColor]) {

    // Yup, update
  //  self.contentView.backgroundColor = contentViewBackgroundColor;

    // Update this, too, to check again later
   // self.contentViewBackgroundColor = contentViewBackgroundColor;
//}

}

- (CGFloat)valueForOption:(ViewPagerOption)option {

switch (option) {
    case ViewPagerOptionTabHeight:
        return [[self tabHeight] floatValue];
    case ViewPagerOptionTabOffset:
        return [[self tabOffset] floatValue];
    case ViewPagerOptionTabWidth:
        return [[self tabWidth] floatValue];
    case ViewPagerOptionTabLocation:
        return [[self tabLocation] floatValue];
    case ViewPagerOptionStartFromSecondTab:
        return [[self startFromSecondTab] floatValue];
    case ViewPagerOptionCenterCurrentTab:
        return [[self centerCurrentTab] floatValue];
    default:
        return NAN;
}
}


-(void)setScrollEnabled:(BOOL)enabled forPageViewController:(UIPageViewController*)pageViewController{
for(UIView* view in pageViewController.view.subviews){
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){
        UIScrollView* scrollView=(UIScrollView*)view;
        [scrollView setScrollEnabled:enabled];
        return;
    }
}
}


- (void)defaultSettings {

// pageViewController
self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll
                                                         navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                                                                        options:nil];



[self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];

// Setup some forwarding events to hijack the scrollView
// Keep a reference to the actual delegate
self.actualDelegate = ((UIScrollView *)[self.pageViewController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0]).delegate;
// Set self as new delegate
((UIScrollView *)[self.pageViewController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0]).delegate = self;

self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
self.pageViewController.delegate = self;

self.animatingToTab = NO;
self.defaultSetupDone = NO;
}
- (void)defaultSetup {

// Empty tabs and contents
for (UIView *tabView in self.tabs) {
    [tabView removeFromSuperview];
}
self.tabsView.contentSize = CGSizeZero;

[self.tabs removeAllObjects];
[self.contents removeAllObjects];

// Get tabCount from dataSource
self.tabCount = [self.dataSource numberOfTabsForViewPager:self];

// Populate arrays with [NSNull null];
self.tabs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.tabCount];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < self.tabCount; i++) {
    [self.tabs addObject:[NSNull null]];
}

self.contents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.tabCount];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < self.tabCount; i++) {
    [self.contents addObject:[NSNull null]];
}

// Add tabsView
self.tabsView = (UIScrollView *)[self.view viewWithTag:kTabViewTag];

if (!self.tabsView) {

    self.tabsView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), [self.tabHeight floatValue])];
    self.tabsView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    self.tabsView.backgroundColor = self.tabsViewBackgroundColor;
    self.tabsView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    self.tabsView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.tabsView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.tabsView.tag = kTabViewTag;

    [self.view insertSubview:self.tabsView atIndex:0];
}

// Add tab views to _tabsView
CGFloat contentSizeWidth = 0;

// Give the standard offset if fixFormerTabsPositions is provided as YES
if ([self.fixFormerTabsPositions boolValue]) {

    // And if the centerCurrentTab is provided as YES fine tune the offset according to it
    if ([self.centerCurrentTab boolValue]) {
        contentSizeWidth = (CGRectGetWidth(self.tabsView.frame) - [self.tabWidth floatValue]) / 2.0;
    } else {
        contentSizeWidth = [self.tabOffset floatValue];
    }
}

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < self.tabCount; i++) {

    UIView *tabView = [self tabViewAtIndex:i];

    CGRect frame = tabView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = contentSizeWidth;
    frame.size.width = [self.tabWidth floatValue];
    tabView.frame = frame;

    [self.tabsView addSubview:tabView];

    contentSizeWidth += CGRectGetWidth(tabView.frame);

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    [tabView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
}

contentSizeWidth=contentSizeWidth-500;

if ([self.fixLatterTabsPositions boolValue]) {

    if ([self.centerCurrentTab boolValue]) {
        contentSizeWidth += (CGRectGetWidth(self.tabsView.frame) - [self.tabWidth floatValue]) / 2.0;
    } else {
        contentSizeWidth += CGRectGetWidth(self.tabsView.frame) - [self.tabWidth floatValue] - [self.tabOffset floatValue];
    }
}

self.tabsView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentSizeWidth, [self.tabHeight floatValue]);

self.contentView = [self.view viewWithTag:kContentViewTag];

if (!self.contentView) {

    self.contentView = self.pageViewController.view;
    self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
   // self.contentView.backgroundColor = self.contentViewBackgroundColor;
    self.contentView.bounds = self.view.bounds;
    self.contentView.tag = kContentViewTag;

    [self.view insertSubview:self.contentView atIndex:0];
}

NSUInteger index = [self.startFromSecondTab boolValue] ? 1 : 0;
[self selectTabAtIndex:index];

self.defaultSetupDone = YES;
}

- (TabView *)tabViewAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

if (index >= self.tabCount) {
    return nil;
}

if ([[self.tabs objectAtIndex:index] isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
    UIView *tabViewContent = [self.dataSource viewPager:self viewForTabAtIndex:index];
    tabViewContent.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    TabView *tabView = [[TabView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, [self.tabWidth floatValue], [self.tabHeight floatValue])];
    [tabView addSubview:tabViewContent];
    [tabView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [tabView setIndicatorColor:self.indicatorColor];

    tabViewContent.center = tabView.center;

    // Replace the null object with tabView
    [self.tabs replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:tabView];
}

return [self.tabs objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

if (index >= self.tabCount) {
    return nil;
}

if ([[self.contents objectAtIndex:index] isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {

    UIViewController *viewController;

    if ([self.dataSource respondsToSelector:@selector(viewPager:contentViewControllerForTabAtIndex:)]) {
        viewController = [self.dataSource viewPager:self contentViewControllerForTabAtIndex:index];
    } else if ([self.dataSource respondsToSelector:@selector(viewPager:contentViewForTabAtIndex:)]) {

        UIView *view = [self.dataSource viewPager:self contentViewForTabAtIndex:index];

        // Adjust view's bounds to match the pageView's bounds
        UIView *pageView = [self.view viewWithTag:kContentViewTag];
        view.frame = pageView.bounds;

        viewController = [UIViewController new];
        viewController.view = view;
    } else {
        viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        viewController.view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    }

    [self.contents replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:viewController];
}

return [self.contents objectAtIndex:index];
}
- (NSUInteger)indexForViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

return [self.contents indexOfObject:viewController];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
NSUInteger index = [self indexForViewController:viewController];
index++;
return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
NSUInteger index = [self indexForViewController:viewController];
index--;
return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}


- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed {

UIViewController *viewController = self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0];

// Select tab
NSUInteger index = [self indexForViewController:viewController];
[self selectTabAtIndex:index];
}
```

I don't want let swipe on this pageviewController I want to handle paging with next and back buttons only, but I can't disable swipe gesture. Is it possible to disable it or is this some other ways remove all gestures in that view?

Comment: Did you check answers to this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098493/uipageviewcontroller-disable-swipe-gesture

Comment: i didn't see that answer but it helps me a lot thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try like this

```
for (UIScrollView *view in self.pageViewController.view.subviews) {

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {

        view.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome , enjoy @ercan

Comment: @Sport can you please help me where i have to write this code?