# Disable Page scrolling in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I am working on app in which I'm using UIPageViewController. Now I want to disable page scrolling not Gestures. actually I want to draw signature in view that contain in UIPageViewController.For this I need to disable page scrolling. 
I've done Gesture disable but it is not what I want.

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in pageViewController.gestureRecognizers)
{
   recognizer.enabled = YES;
}
```

And I want it with the help of Edit button that when I press page scrolling disable and enable with pressing again.
Any body can tell me How will it be possible.

Comment: See [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24847685/3985749)

Answer (score 4):

if You need to disable scrolling in UIPageViewController - You can return nil in data source methods:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```