# Disable and Reenable Page View Controller gesture recogniser?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a page view controller that the user can swipe between views.

I want to stop the user from being able to swipe between the views ridiculously fast by temporarily disabling then reenabling the page view controller gesture recogniser.

How can I programmatically disable and reenable the page view controllers gestures recogniser?

Here is an example of something I am ideally trying to do.

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
{

enableSwiping = NO;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think UIPageViewController has an API to do that sort of thing but by returning only a subset of views from the data source method you can achieve the required behaviour.

Take a look at this question on SO which talks about disabling scrolling for page View controller [Disable Page scrolling in UIPageViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171786/disable-page-scrolling-in-uipageviewcontroller)

So for your requirement you should only return say the first two pages until the user scrolls till second page. Then you can return the next two pages....