# Disable UIPageViewController Swipe - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

In my project i use UIPageViewController to swipe between 5 child UIViewController. In some of child view controller, i need to disable the swipe gesture of the UIPageViewController so when user swipe it not change to other view. 
So how i can disable the swipe from the child view controller?

Appreciate for help..thanks

Comment: when child1 is presenting. userInteraction = false

Comment: Check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74746243/8738937

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your page view controller, add following

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourpageviewcontroller.enableSwipe(_:)), name:"enableSwipe", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourpageviewcontroller.disableSwipe(_:)), name:"disableSwipe", object: nil)

}
func disableSwipe(notification: NSNotification){
    self.dataSource = nil
}

func enableSwipe(notification: NSNotification){
    self.dataSource = self
}
```

In your child view controller, you can just post notification by following.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("enableSwipe", object: nil)
```

OR

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("disableSwipe", object: nil)
```

Comment: Hi, its working for swipe but it also block the scroll up and down since my child has uitableview. How to make the tableview keep scroll also?thanks

Comment: Please check your child view's 'User Interaction Enabled'  and also In your tableView, make sure Scrolling Enabled check box is checked

Comment: it turns out that my logic for checking the offset its wrong. so i accepted the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much, such a clean answer, +1 :)

Comment: This is really what I needed! I didnt know you could do that kind of things with Notification Center! thanks man

Answer (score 6):

You can use this extension:

```
extension UIPageViewController {
     var isPagingEnabled: Bool {
        get {
           var isEnabled: Bool = true
           for view in view.subviews {
               if let subView = view as? UIScrollView {
                   isEnabled = subView.isScrollEnabled
               }
           }
           return isEnabled
       }
       set {
           for view in view.subviews {
               if let subView = view as? UIScrollView {
                   subView.isScrollEnabled = newValue
               }
           }
       }
   }    
}
```

and call this:

```
pageCtrl.isPagingEnabled = false
```

Comment: useful extension

Comment: Unless Apple changes the view hierarchy, i.e. so that the scroll view sits inside a container view of some kind.