# Dragging items while in a UIPageViewController

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have put together a set of pages using UIPageViewController. The first screen is an initial screen, and the user should swipe to the next page after being greeted. The following three screens are tabbed views.

Once the first of these screens loads, I no longer need the ability to swipe from view to view. Instead, I have a set of tabs at the top of the screen to navigate between each page. Upon clicking a tab, the screen scrolls to the next page.

[basic workflow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrzyn.png)

Two of the three pages have dragging abilities. On the first, the user will drag small UIImageViews to a destination. On the second, the user will interact with a chart using touch.

My questions are:

- Is there a way to keep UIPageViewController from moving given a particular index?
- I like the way the tab view scrolls from page to page, just on the last three pages I don't want "side to side" movement. Only when the user clicks a button or tab at the top. Is this possible?
- Would you consider this a good way to implement this sort of UI? I am still relatively new to using Swift/IOS, would UIPageViewController be the best fit for this? If not, what might be a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little digging I found this post:

[How do I Disable the swipe gesture of UIPageViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098493/how-do-i-disable-the-swipe-gesture-of-uipageviewcontroller)

It would appear that disabling the dataSource protocol is what I needed. On the introductory page, I created a swipe behavior to load the next page.