# Stop scrolling UIPageViewController on swipe

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I had use the **UIPageViewController** now I currently I am getting scrolling when I swipe the screen, but I want to do it on button click. It **won't scroll** when I **swipe horizontal on screen**.

I want solution for :

**1. How to Stop scrolling while I swipe on screen horizontaly**

Actually I have seen many solution but I am not getting so I am asking this question .

Comment: Question not clear. Add screens.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please Reframe it again.

Comment: @Daljeet How to stop scroll in UIPageViewController ?

Comment: @Daljeet Got me now ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I Disable the swipe gesture of UIPageViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098493/how-do-i-disable-the-swipe-gesture-of-uipageviewcontroller)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make your `UIPageViewController` `dataSource = nil` and then the scroll will stop.