# UIPageViewController scroll programmatically

Tags: ios, scroll, uipageviewcontroller

I am currently using a UIPageViewController to show several View Controllers. It's like in the Twitter App.

Now I want to scroll programmatically to a visible rect. Not just to the next view by using:

```
[_pager setViewControllers:@[[SFDHelper instantiateVC:@"conferences"]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It is like I wanted to show only a part of the new view Controller.

I have a reference to the UIPageViewControllers scrollview, but calling

```
[_pagersScrollView scrollRectToVisible:scrollRect animated:NO];
```

is not working. 
My Log shows, that it should move, but it doesn't

Comment: No I think it's not possible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208871/is-it-possible-to-turn-page-programmatically-in-uipageviewcontroller This works!