# Next Page Button for UIPageViewController iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I followed **http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/** for creating a PageViewController.

This tutorial contains :
(code for **Restart** button)

```
- (IBAction)restartButton:(id)sender {
PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

When i tried for **Next** button like this:

```
- (IBAction)nextPageButton:(id)sender {
PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:+1];
NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

but it fails, how to perform next page action with the UIButton that responds with the PageControl till last page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208871/is-it-possible-to-turn-page-programmatically-in-uipageviewcontroller/39190174?noredirect=1#comment65723601_39190174 Latest answer can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

That wont work because you are using +1, instead, try this:

```
//get current index of current page
DataViewController *theCurrentViewController = [self.pageViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
NSUInteger retreivedIndex = [self.modelController indexOfViewController:theCurrentViewController];

//check that current page isn't first page
if (retreivedIndex < 5){

    //get the page to go to
    DataViewController *targetPageViewController = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:(retreivedIndex + 1) storyboard:self.storyboard];

    //put it(or them if in landscape view) in an array
    NSArray *theViewControllers = nil;    
    theViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:targetPageViewController, nil];

    //add page view
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:theViewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: Wats that modelController mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
PageNumberToJump=2


-(void)buyAction
{

isFromBuy = YES;

    APPChildViewController *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:PageNumberToJump];
    viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];
    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
}

-(NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{

    if (isFromBuy)
    {
        isFromBuy = NO;
        return PageNumberToJump;
    }
    return 0;

}
```