# Change UIPageViewController page programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I am using UIPageViewController having Next button that have same functionality like swipe to next view.

```
@IBAction func next(sender: UIButton!) {

    let pageContentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers![0] as! WelcomeViewController
    let index = pageContentViewController.pageIndex + 1

    if index < titleArray.count {
        let vctoMove = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index) as WelcomeViewController
        let viewControllers = NSArray(objects: vctoMove)
        pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not working?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489920/ios-swift-uipageviewcontroller-turning-page-programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489920/ios-swift-uipageviewcontroller-turning-page-programatically)

Comment: it change the view but page control indicator not updated