# change pages in UIPageViewController Automatically with timer in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, timer, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have `UIPageViewController` that Contains 4 view Controllers

I set the timer for changing view controllers automatically(going to the next view controllers) - This timer and method will work But the problem is that It works Just for first Slide and when the app will run and after 5 seconds the `UIPageViewController` will show the second slide But after that nothing will happen !
This Is the Code That I used

```
lazy var VCArr : [UIViewController] = {

    return [self.VCInstance(name : "VC1"),
            self.VCInstance(name : "VC2"),
            self.VCInstance(name :"VC3"),
            self.VCInstance(name :"VC4")]
}()

func changeSlide() {

    print("Slide Change!")


    guard let currentViewController = self.VCArr.first  else { return }

            guard let nextViewController = dataSource?.pageViewController( self, viewControllerAfter: currentViewController ) else { return }

            setViewControllers([nextViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

var tTime: Timer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    tTime = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(changeSlide), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    }
```

I think the problem is in this line

```
guard let currentViewController = self.VCArr.first  else { return }
```

But I don't know how to change this line to work fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to Turn page programmatically in UIPageViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208871/is-it-possible-to-turn-page-programmatically-in-uipageviewcontroller)

Comment: Hello i think you are not assign a correct viewController `setViewControllers([nextViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: this is working But Just for first slide

Comment: Problem is in your `nextViewController`. it is always return first view controller

Comment: so how to change that?

Comment: as per you requirement you can use index as follow

Comment: this answer doesn't worked for me because the app has still two errors with VCArr[index] and tells can not convert value of UIViewController to expected argument type [UIViewController]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148849/discussion-between-harshal-valanda-and-saeed-rahmatolahi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

You can change view controller by index of VCArr.

```
var index = 0

func changeSlide() {
    index + 1
    if index < self.VCArr.count {
        setViewControllers([VCArr[index]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        index = 0
        setViewControllers([VCArr[0]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: the doesn't let me to use this code ! I think the problem is index

Comment: add index as a variable and assign with the 0 `var index = 0`

Comment: So after var index = 0 the app has still two errors with VCArr[index] and tells can not convert value of UIViewController to expected argument type  [UIViewController]

Comment: ok This will Work But the problem is just for the last page When from last page wants to go to the first page I will receive fatal Error

Comment: its problem in direction. change direction to backWard

Comment: Thanks A lot It Works!

Comment: @HarshalValanda hello harshal in my case it only works in one direction like when i manually go to 2nd page it automatically reverse but not working with first page. m having 2pages only. please help me out :(.

Comment: @deltami check your direction. if second to first then using a backward and from 1 to 2 then using a forward