# UIPageViewController next button

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to develop a tutorial in Swift. I have a page view controller working with the indicators (http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/) but I want to add a button to go to the next page by clicking it instead of swiping the screen (TODO NextPage).

```
import UIKit

class TutorialViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
var pageTexts: NSArray!
var pageImages: NSArray!
var index: Int = 0

@IBOutlet var button: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.pageTexts = NSArray(objects: "Explore", "Today Widget")
    self.pageImages = NSArray(objects: "background1.jpg", "background2.jpg")

    self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

    let startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index) as TutorialContentViewController
    let viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as! [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 60)

    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> TutorialContentViewController {
    if (index >= self.pageTexts.count) {
        return TutorialContentViewController()
    }

    let vc: TutorialContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TutorialContentViewController") as! TutorialContentViewController

    vc.image = self.pageImages[index] as! String
    vc.text = self.pageTexts[index] as! String
    vc.pageIndex = index
    self.index = index

    self.button.setTitle(self.index == self.pageTexts.count - 1 ? "Finish" : "Next", forState: .Normal)

    return vc
}


// MARK: - Page View Controller Data Source
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let vc = viewController as! TutorialContentViewController
    let index = vc.pageIndex as Int

    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let vc = viewController as! TutorialContentViewController
    var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil
    }

    index++
    if (index == self.pageTexts.count) {
        self.button.setTitle("Finish", forState: .Normal)
        return nil
    } else {
        self.button.setTitle("Next", forState: .Normal)
    }
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
}

func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return self.pageTexts.count
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
}

@IBAction func onButtonClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (self.index == self.pageTexts.count - 1) {
        let vc : UIViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("splashViewController")
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion:nil)
    } else {
        //TODO NextPage
    }
}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208871/is-it-possible-to-turn-page-programmatically-in-uipageviewcontroller/39190174?noredirect=1#comment65723601_39190174 Latest answer can be helpful

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

For next page

```
@IBAction func onButtonNextClick(sender: object) {
    pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers,
                                                    direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward,
                                                    animated: true,
                                                    completion: nil)
}
```

For previous page

```
@IBAction func onButtonPreviousClick(sender: object) {
    pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers,
                                                    direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Reverse,
                                                    animated: true,
                                                    completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: How do you define viewControllers?

Comment: Which one that you defined here `    let startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index) as TutorialContentViewController
    let viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)`. You should create a property for it.

Comment: It goes to the next page, but does not update the circle page indicator and then all pages are the current page (always the second page)

Comment: @YamiFraiman did you manage to work this issue out? I cannot get page indicators updated too

Comment: @Gulz no, I gave up.

Comment: This approach will not call delegate method

Answer (score 0):

A quick way would be to subclass `UIPageViewController` and put your button action in there making use of the datasource and delegate as follows:

```
@implementation MyPageViewController

- (IBAction)nextPage:(id)sender{
    NSArray *previousControllers = self.viewControllers;
    UIViewController *controller = [self.dataSource pageViewController:self viewControllerAfterViewController:previousControllers.firstObject];
    if(!controller){
        return;
    }
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [self setViewControllers:@[controller] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [weakSelf.delegate pageViewController:weakSelf didFinishAnimating:finished previousViewControllers:previousControllers transitionCompleted:YES];
        // if you need more than one line of code you must make a strongSelf = weakSelf variable first
    }];
}
```

You could also make use of `presentationCountForPageViewController` and `presentationIndexForPageViewController` for disabling/enabling the button if at the page boundaries.