# setViewControllers doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I'm trying to change the current ViewController of my UIPageViewController using a NEXT button. So I'm calling the function that's in my containterViewController in my mainViewController using a delegate. But it doesn't execute the setViewControllers line.

Here you can see my code:

This is the method that I call using my delegate:

```
func forwardPage() {
    print("Start")
    currentPage += 1
    print(vcs[currentPage])
    self.setViewControllers([vcs[currentPage]], direction: .forward, animated: true) { (true) in
        print("Done")
    }
}
```

Here's my delegate:

```
protocol WalkthroughViewControllerDelegate {
   func forwardPage()
   func currentIndex() -> Int
}
```

And here's the function that is connected to my NEXT button:

```
@IBAction func nextButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if let index = delegate?.currentIndex() {
        print("Here... \(index)")
        switch index {
        case 0...1:
            print("Forwarding...")
            delegate?.forwardPage()
        case 2:
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        default: break
        }
    }

    updateUI()
}
```

Everything but the "Done" gets printed

I would really appreciate your help

I've been struggling because of this for quite some time now

Thank you very much :)

EDIT: Maybe this happens because that UIPageViewController is inside a containerView. But I'm not sure

SECOND EDIT: I've created a git-hub repository just for this issue. Here's the link: https://github.com/LennartPhil/App-Popup-Screen. I hope you can understand that I won't show you all of my files.

Comment: *"I'm calling the function that's in my containterViewController"* ... Is `forwardPage()` in your `UIPageViewController` class? In other words, is `self` there an instance of `UIPageViewController`?

Comment: And... I did my test with a page view controller embedded in a containerView, so that's not the issue (unless you're func is in the wrong place).

Comment: Yes, `self` is of type `UIPageViewController`

Comment: Hmm... not sure then why your code is not working. Have you stepped through it to inspect your vars? I have a simple example project that uses an embedded Page View Controller, along with buttons to programmatically change pages... and the trailing completion block *does* get called. You can take a look, and compare my approach to yours to see if anything jumps out: https://github.com/DonMag/EmbeddedPageView

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately, I can't really find anything that could help me. But thx anyways, I really appreciate it a lot :)

Comment: Well, another thought... your initial question said *"it doesn't execute the setViewControllers line"* ... Does that mean your page doesn't change? Or it changes, but "Done" doesn't get printed to the console?

Comment: The page doesn't change and "Done" doesn't get printed, so both

Comment: OK - if your "page" doesn't change, it sounds like you indexing is off, and you are calling `setViewControllers` with the currently displayed VC (and the completion doesn't get called because you didn't actually change the VC). Try changing `currentPage += 1` to `currentPage = self.currentIndex() + 1` and see if that changes the page.

Comment: Unfortunately, the result didn't change: I can swipe through the different ViewControllers but once I press the NextButton nothing happens. But I really appreciate how devoted you are to solving my problem. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I expect you need to look closely at your indexing. Even if the page isn't visually changing, your code *appears* to be incrementing a `currentPage` variable. So, if you tap next, next, next, does your `currentIndex()` func return 0, 1, 2?

Comment: The weird thing is that the index is correct. I print out the index and it's the right one, that's why I am so confused. And yes the `currentIndex()` function does return 0, 1, 2

Comment: Have you looked at copying another example of the setViewControllers method? - [how about this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208871/is-it-possible-to-turn-page-programmatically-in-uipageviewcontroller)

Comment: @LennartP. Did you see `self.setViewControllers` is an asynchronous call and you're updating the UI just after this? `updateUI()` will be call before printing the "Done" so you should update the UI somehow inside this completion block.

Comment: @LennartP. -- I think you need to show a bit more of your code. You must be doing *something* else that's preventing the "page change". I modified my sample app (that I linked to above) to use a delegate pattern as you're using, and still have no problem - it shows the next page as desired. And just to be clear... your `forwardPage()` func *is* being executed? You get "Start" printed to the console? If so, add a `print(self.viewControllers)` immediately before `print(vcs[currentPage])` and make sure it's not the same VC.

Comment: Are you using this example? https://github.com/n6xej/CSWXIBWalkThrough

Comment: @LennartP. -- and... what's going on in `updateUI()`? Are you inadvertently setting the current page back to the one you just tried to change?

Comment: Can you take a snapshot of your view hierarchy and paste it?

Comment: are there any compiler warnings? for example:  { (true) in
        print("Done")
    } should be: { _ in
print("Done")
}

Comment: How are you setting the delegate(pageViewController) of the container view?

Comment: I added a link to all the files so you can check them out if you want to. Don't worry, there are just two main files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - the problem is that your code in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ExtraViewControllers", bundle: nil)
    let walkthroughPageVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WalkthroughPageVC") as! WalkthroughPageViewController
    delegate = walkthroughPageVC
```

is creating a NEW instance of `WalkthroughPageViewController`, which goes out of scope as soon as `viewDidLoad()` exits. So it no longer exists.

What you need to do instead is get a reference to it in `prepare(for segue:...)`, and set it as your delegate there:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? WalkthroughPageViewController {
        self.delegate = vc
    }
}
```

I forked your GitHub repo and added the files into a project, so you can see it run: https://github.com/DonMag/App-Popup-Screen

Comment: Thank you so so much! I'm so incredibly happy right now :) That's really amazing, thank you ^^